# trigger SEQUENCE after each SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sequence, plpgsql, sql-function

I have created a Sequence and I want trigger it after each SELECT query on table

```
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS kadry.wyplaty_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE kadry.wyplaty_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 7771
  CACHE 1;
```

So I am trying to create a function like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION kadry.inc_trig()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS  
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('kadry.wyplaty_seq');
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

And in the end create a trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS increment_trigger ON kadry.wyplaty;
CREATE TRIGGER increment_trigger AFTER SELECT 
    ON kadry.wyplaty 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE kadry.inc_trig();
```

Problem is in this line

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_trigger AFTER SELECT
```

And i know should looks like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_trigger AFTER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
```

Does anybody know what should i do to trigger my function after each SELECT query?

Comment: You **cannot** fire a trigger on Select. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html)).

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to achieve from business perspective? Is it some kind of auditing?

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda This is just a student exercise and this is not a part of a bigger project. Just have small database and I have to testing some short function like in question

Comment: So the answer is, no you cannot use trigger for it

Comment: You may find an answer to a very similar issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217314/read-amount-on-a-postgres-table) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as trigger on SELECT. SELECT by design should also does not have any side effects.

---

With saying so here is really ugly way:

Wrapping query with function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_wyplaty()
RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER)
AS $$
DECLARE 
     b    integer;
BEGIN
    b := nextval('wyplaty_seq');
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM wyplaty;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And querying function instead of table:

```
SELECT * FROM f_wyplaty();
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b538470ef74e3de410d996337aa66867)**