# Read amount on a postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql

Is there any way to calculate the amount of read per second on a Postgres table?

but what I need is that whether a table has any read at the moment. (If no, then I can safely drop it)

Thank you

Comment: If a table is read (=in use) at the moment you can't drop it anyway.

Comment: it's not in use, but imagine that you have 1 read request every 30minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figure out if the table is used currently, tun

```
SELECT pid
FROM pg_locks
WHERE relation = 'mytable'::regclass;
```

That will return the process ID of all backends using it.

To measure whether s table is used at all or not, run this query:

```
SELECT seq_scan + idx_scan + n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE relname = 'mytable';
```

Then repeat the query in a day. If the numbers haven't changed, nobody has used the table.

Comment: Doesn't auto analyze also increase the values in `pg_stat_user_tables`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not these ones, I think. And if the table is not used at all, why should autoanalyze run on it?

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure. I though I had read something about aut-analyze would change it. But if it doesn't, fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Audit SELECT activity**

My suggestion is to wrap `mytable` in a view (called `the_view_to_use_instead` in the example) which invokes a logging function upon every `select` and then use the view for selecting from, i.e.

```sql
select <whatever you need> from the_view_to_use_instead ...
```

instead of

```sql
select <whatever you need> from mytable ...
```

So here it is

```sql
create table audit_log (table_name text, event_time timestamptz);

create function log_audit_event(tname text) returns void language sql as
$$
 insert into audit_log values (tname, now());
$$;

create view the_view_to_use_instead as
 select mytable.* 
 from mytable, log_audit_event('mytable') as ignored;
```

Every time someone queries `the_view_to_use_instead` an audit record with a timestamp appears in table `audit_log`. You can then examine it in order to find out whether and when `mytable` was selected from and make your decision. Function `log_audit_event` can be reused in other similar scenarios. The average number of selects per second over the last 24 hours would be

```sql
select count(*)::numeric/86400
 from audit_log
 where event_time > now() - interval '86400 seconds';
```